# My Ubuntu 18.04 auto screen-resize doesn't work

Tags: screen, resize, snap-windows

The auto resize feature is not working on my Ubuntu 18.04. I even tried Unity Tweak, but this also doesn't work.
I used to use this feature in my Ubuntu 16.04 a lot, dragging my open windows to the sides and Ubuntu does the resizing job for me automatically. But, since I have installed 18.04, it doesn't work.